# Can you apply more than one Javascript effect to an element?

Tags: javascript

I have a directional arrow that toggles a nav menu (with hide/show js) but when I try to add a shake animation to the same directional arrow, it won't show the shake animation.

Comment: The answer would be "it depends on how the effects are programmed". Add your code to the question.

Comment: Is this question about some particular JS library?

Comment: use delay property, first animation end then start second effect.